# Join Field to Range of Values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to extract data from a table that references transactions from another table.  I cannot figure out how to obtain the desired output.

**Table1:**

```
+--------+-------------+---------+
| Widget | SequenceNbr | Amount  |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| Thing1 |       12345 |  100.00 |
| Thing1 |       12346 |  110.00 |
| Thing2 |       12345 |   98.25 |
| Thing2 |       12347 |  877.99 |
| Thing3 |       12333 |  638.00 |
+--------+-------------+---------+
```

**Table2:**

```
+----------+------------------+----------------+
| BatchNbr | BeginSequenceNbr | EndSequenceNBr |
+----------+------------------+----------------+
|     9998 |            12300 |          12345 |
|     9999 |            12346 |          12350 |
+----------+------------------+----------------+
```

I have tried to create using `group by` for `first` / `last` and different join scenarios.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.[Widget],
    Table1.[SequenceNbr],
    Table1.[Amount], 
    Table2.[BatchNbr]
FROM 
    Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON 
    (Table2.BeginSequenceNbr) AND 
    (Table2.EndSequenceNbr = Table1.[SequenceNbr])
WHERE 
    (((Table1.[SequenceNbr]) Between [Enter Begin Sequence Nbr] And [Enter End Sequence Nbr])));
```

If parameter query Sequence Range `12300` to `12346`, then the desired output is

```
Thing1, 12345, 100.00, 9998
Thing1, 12346, 110.00, 9999
Thing2, 12345, 98.25, 9998
Thing3, 12333, 638.00, 9998
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select
    t1.widget, 
    t1.sequencenbr, 
    t1.amount, 
    t2.batchnbr
from
    table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on
    t1.sequencenbr >= t2.beginsequencenbr and  
    t1.sequencenbr <= t2.endsequencenbr
```

Note that MS Access will not be able to represent the join in the Query Designer, but the JET Database Engine used by MS Access should still be able to execute this valid SQL.